# How would one make a non-toxic pen out of osmium?

Tags: metal, density

[Osmium is the densest element in the periodic table.](https://www.google.com/search?q=densest%20element) However, it is toxic in its pure form. Is there a way to create a standard pen out of osmium but coat it in a dense material that isn't toxic to have the heaviest pen?

How would this pen be made?

It would be a cap pen (like the Uniball pen pictured below) with no wasted space for plastic mechanical parts.

[image: Uniball Pen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Osmium alloys with many metals, [so it could be covered by an alloy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmium#Applications). [Osmiridium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmiridium), an alloy with iridium, is even harder than pure osmium.

It would seem possible to dip the osmium pen blank in an iridium or osmiridium bath (at rather *high* temperature) to produce a long-lasting casing, rather like dipped chocolate cordials.

If you accept this answer, I'd be glad to receive an award of one of these pens. ;-)

Comment: I'm not making these pens, I was just curious. If I was I would give you one ;). Also, osmiridium is nontoxic?

Comment: It's considered safe, and is already used for fountain-pen tips: http://pro.tanaka.co.jp/en/library/element/column08/

Comment: It turns out that a working pen made out of osmiridium (let's say it uses 45g as 4cm3 with some hollowness) would be about 0.8oz of osmiridium, roughly worth $360. Probably not going to happen anytime soon.

Comment: (Note that I have not measured an approximation of the pen I would like it to be modeled after, so my volume measurement is most likely incorrect) [SO app wouldn't let me edit the comment again]